# Find Resolution of Camera programmatically

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, resolution

I am trying to figure out the resolution of android phones in my app.
I was using

```
public float getBackCameraResolutionInMp() {

    try {
        int noOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        float maxResolution = -1;
        long pixelCount = -1;
        Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(BACK_CAMERA_ID, cameraInfo);
        if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
            try {
                releaseCameraAndPreview();
                if (camera == null) {
                    camera = Camera.open(BACK_CAMERA_ID);
                }
                Camera.Parameters cameraParams = camera.getParameters();
                for (int j = 0; j < cameraParams.getSupportedPictureSizes().size(); j++) {
                    long pixelCountTemp = cameraParams.getSupportedPictureSizes().get(j).width * cameraParams.getSupportedPictureSizes().get(j).height; // Just changed i to j in this loop
                    if (pixelCountTemp > pixelCount) {
                        pixelCount = pixelCountTemp;
                        maxResolution = ((float) pixelCountTemp) / (1024000.0f);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return maxResolution;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logException(e, "CameraInfoFragment_getBackCameraResolutionInMp()");
        return -1;
    }

}
```

But it returns me approximate resolution not the exact. Like if the resolution is 16MP it returns me 15.55 MP. Can you please help me how to fugure out the exact resolution of camera?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get real Camera max Megapixels of a device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25590721/how-to-get-real-camera-max-megapixels-of-a-device)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not divide by `1024000` but with `1000000`. Here we are talking about `Mega Pixels` not `Mega Bytes` to use the the equality `1 Megabyte = 1,048,576 Bytes` but `1 Megapixel = 1,000,000 Pixels`. Plus `1024000` is wrong, it should have been `1048576` or `2^20`. Dividing by a `1000000` will give you a number much more closer to 16MP.